# Why is my AWS instance not reachable?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, amazon-ami

Yesterday, I created a new instance but I cannot connect to it. Tried pinging it from my computer, online ping sites etc but it is just not reachable.

In the AWS console. everything seems to be functioning normally. The reachability check is successful. Screenshots are given below :

[image: AWS Console screenshot]

[image]

I tried using **different AMIs**, regions but to no avail. I just cannot connect to any AWS instance.

Please help. I'm clueless right now.

[image]

Comment: Have you adjusted the Security Group for that instance to allow connections from your location?  I don't recall if ICMP (e.g., ping) is allowed by default.

Comment: The reason i tried ping is because the host was not reachable via ssh. I have another instance in another account and its 'pingable'. How do i adjust the security group to allow connections ?

Comment: There's a Security Group in the navigation plane of the control panel.  Create a new one or change the default.  When you start up an instance, you will be asked what Security Groups apply to that instance.

Comment: added screenshot for the security group incoming settings. looks okay to me ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you allow ICMP and other traffic in security group settings? You should check the security group settings. It looks like you are using a default security group as seen on the 2nd row of 2nd column of the table on your screenshot. You should click "view rules" and adjust the rules there.

Comment: added screenshot for the security group incoming settings

Comment: Well you seem to be dropping all incoming connections

Comment: i'm sorry i dont understand. Are the security settings wrong ?

Comment: the security settings blocked all the ports ! I thought it was the other way round ! Thanks ! Accepted answer for you.

Comment: Not exactly wrong but just too restrictive, you only allow incoming connections from `sg-....` which I guess is related to your Amazon infrastructure but not the public web. You should a set of rules to allow hosts from `0.0.0.0/0` to access certain TCP ports or to ping the hosts in this security group.